# How to load different menu based on current page in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have inherited a site from a new client who has a wordpress site that was heavily hand-coded by their previous webdev. The current code (in the header.php file) is:

```
//When page loads...
    $(".tab").hide(); //Hide all content
//Find URL location
var idToShow = location.pathname.split("/")[1];
//If URL location is one of these, then show its proper menu. If it isn't just show the home's menu.
if (idToShow == "unknown" || idToShow == "home" || idToShow == "parish" || idToShow == "formation" || idToShow == "school" || idToShow == "youth-ministry" || idToShow == "councils" || idToShow == "committees" || idToShow == "organizationsactivites" || idToShow == "contact") {
    $("#nav li."+idToShow).addClass("current").show(); //Activate first tab
    $("#"+idToShow).show();
}
else {
    $("#nav li.home").addClass("current").show(); //Activate first tab
    $("#home").show();
}
```

I am in the process of moving this site to a new host, and this works on the old host, but *not* the new host. I'm not sure where I could look for error logs (if there are any) or any other information that would help me solve this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: errors in the console? is the slug/permalink settings the same?

Comment: Are you using the root url on both hosts? This line: var idToShow = location.pathname.split("/")[1] will break if your url structure changes due to the hardcoded 1.

Comment: Right now, we have the site on the new host running on an IP address. We have done search & replace on the database as well as on theme files to get everything working. @atmd I don't have access to the server console if that is what you are referencing.

Comment: no the console in dev tools

Comment: @atmd Ah, that makes more sense. There are no errors except for a MIME type error, but I assume it isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
//When page loads...
    $(".tab").hide(); //Hide all content
//Find URL location
var idToShow = location.pathname.split("/")[1];
//If URL location is one of these, then show its proper menu. If it isn't just show the home's menu.
if (idToShow == "unknown" || idToShow == "home" || idToShow == "parish" || idToShow == "formation" || idToShow == "school" || idToShow == "youth-ministry" || idToShow == "councils" || idToShow == "committees" || idToShow == "organizationsactivites" || idToShow == "contact") {
    $("#nav li."+idToShow).addClass("current").show(); //Activate first tab
    $("#"+idToShow).show();
}
else {
    $("#nav li.home").addClass("current").show(); //Activate first tab
    $("#home").show();
}
});
```

Hello, try this. This will solve your problem.